# In viewpager, checkbox state loss on swipe. what is logic behind this scenario

Tags: android, android-fragments, checkbox, android-viewpager, radio-button

I have viewpager which has multiple fragments.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <CheckBox android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:text="Do you need recurring" />
  <RadioGroup android:id="@+id/rdgrpEnd"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_margin="@dimen/most_most_most_min_margin"
              android:gravity="left|start"
              android:orientation="vertical">

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/rdbtnNever"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.3"
                            android:padding="@dimen/min_margin"
                            android:text="Never " />

                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/rdbtnAfter"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.3"
                            android:padding="@dimen/min_margin"
                            android:text="After" />
                        <RadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/rdbtnOn"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="0.3"
                            android:padding="@dimen/min_margin"
                            android:text="After" />
    </RadioGroup>

 </LinearLayout>
```

with this i got no error on this. My doubt is, My viewpager has 15 fragments and which doesn't have setOffscreenPageLimit() function. I I checked both check box and radio button. I swiped to last fragment. ex: 15th fragment.now i am back to first fragment which i checked on before swipe to 15th fragment. Here, CheckBox lost it's state.(Here unchecked) but radio button has it's state(Here checked state) .what is the logic behind this.

**UPDATE**

```
public class NewAppointmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


List<Long> listItems;
private Context context;

public NewAppointmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Long> listItems) {
    super(fm);
    this.listItems = listItems;
}


public void setContext(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    ChildFragmentNewAppointmentItems fragment = new ChildFragmentNewAppointmentItems();
    fragment.setData(listItems.get(position));
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listItems.size();
}
}
```

**UPDATE**

listitem is for dynamic fragment creation  which holds the date (Data Type is Long) . i am creating the tab and fragments based on date. Fragment which hold the view of checkbox and radio button. According to the docs, viewpager will destroy entire views of the fragment other than one from right of the current view and another one left of the current view. so, i travelled 0th fragment to my last 14th fragment after checked the state of the component. when i back to the 0th fragment,checkbox state worked perfectly whereas radio button state is not. Why?

Comment: I've tried but `checkbox` did not lost state. show your Adapter code as well as how do you set it to the `viewpager`.

Comment: I didn't maintain the state of mentioned component. Just used basic adapter. Even i update my adapter code also

Comment: I am asking what is the logic behind that.

Comment: So the checkbox state change according to `listItems.get(position)`?

Comment: listitem is for dynamic fragment creation  which holds the date (Data Type is Long) . i am creating the tab and fragments based on date. Fragment which hold the view of checkbox and radio button.

Comment: Okay..Try to override `onRestoreInstanceState()` with an empty body, not event `super`. It will help to figure out the problem.